# Liquibase logging level in Spring Boot

Tags: logging, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm using **Spring Boot** and **liquibase** for database migrations and refactorings.

I'm having some exceptions (mostly database exception) in my changesets every now and then, but liquibase shares too little information in the **default log level**. For example it doesn't tell me the exact **SQL statement** it executed or the **name of the CSV file** it was processing when it failed.

Do you know any way to configure liquibase's logLevel to **DEBUG** either through Spring Boot's application.properties or any other non-painful way?

I tried the logging.level.* setting in various combinations but it didn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's a limitation of Spring Boot's code that adapts Liquibase's own logging framework to use Commons Logging. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2916) so that we can improve the adapter.

Now that the issue has been fixed, you can use `logging.level.liquibase` to control the level of Liquibase logging that will be output.

Comment: Is it fixed by now and if yes, what should we do to turn on Liquibase logging in Spring Boot apps?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using log4j then I think adding lines like

```
<Logger name="liquibase" additivity="false" level="debug">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="default-file"/>
</Logger>
```

to your log4j configuration file should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The default logger factory in liquibase uses Java logging ([ref](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/logging/LogService.java)). You can therefore add a `logging.properties` file to control liquibase logging. Here's an [example](https://mkyong.com/logging/logging-properties-example/).

Communicating the location of that file is a little inconvenient as the default location is under JAVA_HOME. You can control this with the `java.util.logging.config.file` system property.